# Не получается добавить hover эффект кнопкам

Tags: html, jquery, css, button

Всем привет! Хочу сделать так, чтобы на кнопке + и - появлялся hover - не получается.. привожу код

```js
$(".plus").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass(button - hover);
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass(button - hover);
  }
);

$(".minus").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass(button - hover);
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass(button - hover);
  }
);
```

```css
.button-hover {
  background-color: #330303;
}
```

```html
<div class="quantity buttons_added">
  <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="27" id="num_count" name="quantity" value="1" title="Кол." class="input-text qty text" size="4">
  <span>порц.</span>
  <input type="button" value="+1" id="button_plus" class="plus">
  <input type="button" value="-1" id="button_minus" class="minus">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ Regent'a верный, но зачем вы изобретаете велосипед на js, если нужный вам эффект можно реализовать на css в две строчки?

```
.plus:hover, .minus:hover{background-color: #330303;}
```

Или вам необходимо использовать ховер именно классом?

Comment: mJeevas, если бы так все было просто - я бы не стремился через js это решить. ховер на пустых импутах не работает - для этого нужен какой-либо текст, а там только value..

Comment: как оказалось - вверху стоял стиль
.product-quantity .quantity > input[type='button'] { background-color: #e4e4e2!important;} и хоть ховер стоял ниже, все равно бекграунд его переопределял. Оказывается, для инпутов бекграунд important срабатывает и для ховера - не знал, заметка на будущее.

Answer (score 1):

Для добавления и удаления класса `button-hover` код должен быть такой: `.addClass("button-hover")` и, соответственно, `.removeClass("button-hover")`.

А `(button - hover)` представляет собой разность значений переменных `button` и `hover`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".plus").hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass("button-hover");
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("button-hover");
    });

    $(".minus").hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass("button-hover");
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("button-hover");
    });
});
```

```css
.button-hover {
    background-color: #330303;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity buttons_added">
    <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="27" id="num_count" name="quantity" value="1" title="Кол." class="input-text qty text" size="4" />
    <span>порц.</span>

    <input type="button" value="+1" id="button_plus" class="plus" />
    <input type="button" value="-1" id="button_minus" class="minus" />
</div>
```

[Пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqkk0Lx3/).

Comment: к сожалению, но даже ваш пример у меня не сработал..
возможно все дело в вордпресс? но я подключил скрипт в тему и console.log без проблем с этого же скрипта вызывается..

Comment: @Вася тогда стоит обернуть весь код в `document.ready`. Изменённый код - в ответе. И, конечно, необходимо подключить jQuery перед этим скриптом.

Comment: jquery уже подключен в wordpress, но что может быть в коде не так?
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

$(document).ready(function($) {
 "use strict";

$(".plus").hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("button-hover");
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("button-hover");
});

$(".minus").hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("button-hover");
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("button-hover");
});

});

Comment: @Вася возможно, элементы создаются (пересоздаются) динамически? Либо где-то в скрипте (не в коде из вопроса, а где-то ещё) есть синтаксическая ошибка.

Comment: меня вот что смущает..что там каждому инпуту назначен айдишник, а у меня пачка товаров выводится и соответственно выводятся все на одной странице..?

Comment: @Вася не понял что именно смущает в пачке товаров.

Comment: то что на странице получается куча id c button_plus и button_minus, а по логике html больше одного id на странице указывать нельзя

Comment: @Вася да, некрасивое дело, но на код в вопросе и ответе это не влияет: и там, и там используются классы для выбора элементов.